# Python -- list(some_float) fails but [some_float] works?

Tags: python, list

I have a case where a user passes a function a single floating-point value. While trying to put that value into a list for easier data handling later, I've discovered that I cannot make a list using `list(some_float)`, but `[some_float]` does work. Python prints an error stating that "'float' object is not iterable."

My question for you wonderful people is why `[]` works, but `list()` does not. My understanding is that they produce identical results even if they are executed differently. I am using Python 3.4.3.

Comment: `list(1, 2)` doesn't work either

Comment: You can use list([1.5]), list (1.5) doesn't work because you can't iterate over a float.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list(thing)` doesn't mean "put `thing` in a list". It means "put `thing`'s **elements** in a list". If you want to put a `thing` in a list, that's `[thing]`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: If you want a tuple, or a set, then yeah. If you want a list, you want `[thing]`.

Comment: That is exactly the succinct explanation I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @user2357112 I meant `list((thing,))`, or list(`{thing}` etc. sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass iterable item

```
print list.__doc__
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
```